# SQL SELECT then UPDATE in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to randomly select a row from a MySQL DataBase, then increment by one a counter on that row (same table). At the moment, I'm running

```
SELECT id, img, title, alt, ... FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

and then separately

```
UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = $id
```

Thus running two queries. Is there a way to do this all in one query?
Thanks!

Comment: Update and select can't be run in a single query. You have to make procedure rather to make them running simultaneously.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That's a pitty. What do you mean by 'make procedure'?

Comment: it simply means a transaction in which you use both these queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to increment the value and not bring back a row to process you could do the following:-

```
UPDATE fred
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM fred
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
) sub0
ON fred.id = sub0.id
SET fred.counter = fred.counter + 1
```

Or simpler:-

```
UPDATE fred
SET fred.counter = fred.counter + 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I _do_ need to work on the returned row.

Comment: Afraid then it isn't possible.

Comment: Well, no big deal then. Just a question - is `sub0` an arbitrary 'name' you give to the result of `SELECT id FROM fred ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Yes. Any sub query in a join must have an alias. I tend to just use sub and a number (so if there is more than 1 sub query used in a join I just use sub0, sub1, etc). Although looking at the query the sub query isn't really necessary.